# How to format Date using dateDropper Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am unable to format a date using the dateDropper jQuery plugin. I tried using `data` attributes in the HTML tag and the JSON option, but without success.

The plugin works fine the only problem is I cannot format the date to `d-m-Y` format instead of `d/m/Y` which is the default option.

```html
<input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday" data-lang="fr" data-large-mode="true" data-dd-format="d-m-Y" data-id="datedropper-0" data-theme="my-style" class="form-control">
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#birthday').dateDropper({
    format: 'd-m-y'
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the documentation says to use `data-dd-format=""` for defining options inline, but for me it only worked if I use `data-format=""`.  As for why it wouldn't work when you define the format in JS, the only thing that I could think of that would cause that is if your JS code is placed before the datedropper.js file is loaded.  Otherwise, it should work with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be your 'y' in  'd-m-y', it's lower case, try the following:

```
 $('#birthday').dateDropper({
     format: 'd-m-Y'
 });
```

Comment: Same problem :/